# vTiger .net C# sales order fails - MANDATORY_FIELDS_MISSING “message”:"

Tags: c#, .net, vtiger

Throwing an exception when I trying to create sales order in VTiger version 6.15.7.6

Sending the following entity 
for Sales order creation

```
            VTigerListItem[] arrListItem = new VTigerListItem[1];
            arrListItem[0] = new VTigerListItem() { productid = "25x405",     listprice = "468.25", quantity = "1" };
            VTigerSalesOrder[] arrListItem1 = new VTigerSalesOrder[1];                
            arrListItem1[0] = new VTigerSalesOrder()
            {
                start_period = "2015-01-01",
                end_period = "2015-01-01",
                subject = "Testing",
                contact_id = "4x680",
                sostatus = SoStatus.Created,
                account_id = "3x679",
                assigned_user_id = "19x11",
                bill_street = "test bill street",
                invoicestatus = Invoicestatus.Created,
                productid = "25x405",                   
                cf_1121 = "RDMS",
                createdtime = "2015-01-01",
                modifiedtime = "2015-01-01",
                LineItems = arrListItem
            };  

            var desc = vtigerApi.Create(arrListItem1[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Contactid , Accountid and Productid.
Module ids are given wrong.
Contacts start with 12X,
Accounts start with 11X,
Products start with 14X,
assign_user_id if it is assigning to User then 19X, if it is assigning to Group then 20X. Also change contact_id to contactid,account_id to accountid.